# Unexpected variable conversion in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to load some paginated data from a server, in TypeScript.

However, one of the variables is getting converted in what seems to be a very strange way.

I created a small test program to replicate the behavior - but it doesn't replicate.  Instead, the small test program does what I was expecting the larger application to do.

Here's my small test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var q = {page: '1', results: '1'};
var si = '1';

interface aqm {
    [key: string]: string | number;
}

function uasekq(si: string, q: aqm = {}, foo: string) {
    console.log(si);
    console.log(q);
    console.log(foo);
}

uasekq(si, q, "abc");
```

And here's what the large application is transpiling to (javascript):

```
function uasekq(si) {
    var q = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== void 0 ? arguments[1] : {}, options = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== void 0 ? arguments[2] : {};
    var temp = (0,_cuaq__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"])((0,_shsosm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])({
        queryKey: [
            "s",
            si,
            "aek"
        ],
        pathname: "/v3/keys/storage/:si",
        q: (0,_shsospm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["default"])((0,_shsosm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"])({}, q), {
            si: si
        })
    }, options));
    return temp;
}
```

In both the small test program and the large application, here's what is being passed as q.  It is also precisely what the small test program receives as q:

```
{page: '1', results: '25'}
```

And still in the large application, here's what seems to be getting received as q:

```
Arguments(2) [undefined, {…}, callee: (...), Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ]
0: undefined
1: {page: '1', results: '25'}
callee: (...)
length: 2
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
get callee: ƒ ()
set callee: ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here's the original (minified) typescript function, and what's calling it:

```
// Called with:
// const { d: ek, il } = uasekq(si, q);
// ...from another file.

interface aqm {
    [k: string]: string | number;
}

function uasekq(
    si: string,
    q: aqm = {},
    o: p<uaqo<pr<ek>>> = {}
) {
    var temp = uaq<pr<ek>>({
        qk: ['s', si, 'aek'],
        p: '/v/k/s/:si',
        q: { ...q, si },
        ...o,
    });
    return temp;
}
```

What is going on there?  It's like it's trying to turn the key-value pairs into a numerically indexed array or something.

We're using typescript@4.9.5.  I wonder if it'd help to upgrade to 5.3.3?
I tried upgrading to typescript 5.3.3 and got compilation errors.  So I tried typescript@4.9.5 instead; the software compiled, but still has the bug.

Comment: It looks like you are logging an `arguments` object where you should only be logging `arguments[1]` (i.e. the second argument). But that is not what the code is assigning to `q`.

Comment: Can you show us the original code that is being transpiled to the snippet you posted? In particular, what are these imported functions that you're calling?

Comment: The value for `var q` in the transpiled function looks fine. So, it may not be the `uasqkq` function itself but whatever called it? And why are you getting `undefined` as the first argument rather than a string? There seems to be no value for `foo` either

Comment: @Bergi I don't think the imported functions should matter, since it's q that's having the problem. ?

Comment: @dstromberg No, the `var q = …` has no problem. But maybe the `q: …` that is passed as an option next to `queryKey` and `pathname` has a problem.

Comment: …and also it might be overwritten by `options.q`

Comment: Hm those functions appear to just be [Babel's object spread syntax transpilation to `Object.assign`](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread), though it's rather weird that it uses `_shsospm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["default"]` in the one place and `_shsosm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["default"]` in the other. Try disabling that babel plugin to see if the result changes.

Comment: @Bergi I looked up the value of q with Chrome's debugger from the very beginning of uasekq.

Comment: @dstromberg do you have source maps enabled? They might mess with your debugger.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I have sourcemap enabled.

Comment: @Bergi We are making heavy, but indirect, use of babel.  That is, it's not in our package.json, but appears throughout our package-lock.json .  Do you still think there may be a way to disable it?

Comment: @dstromberg I mean disable sourcemaps in your debugger to debug the raw code, not prevent babel from creating them. Also try evaluating `q` in the console when halted at a breakpoint in the function, instead of looking at the call stack view.

Comment: @dstromberg Oh wait I misunderstood. For preventing Babel from transpiling the object spread syntax, that only works when the original typescript code is yours, not part of a dependency. I had assumed that `uasekq` is your code? Then even if you're not calling babel directly, there should be a way to pass the options to it; but I don't know your build chain and cannot give advice on that. It might not be necessary though. Just ensure that the functions that are called on the objects don't do anything weird, by stepping into them with the debugger.

Comment: @Bergi I've actually been using the debugger all along, though I do sometimes change stack frames through the debugger.

Comment: @Bergi uasekq is our code, not a dependency.

Comment: I removed the default values for q and o, and it started working.  Something's very wrong with default values in this case, I guess.

Comment: In `const { d: ek, il } = uasekq(si, q)` I'm not sure what the `q` in the other file is supposed to be, but what it *looks* like is that *the other file* mistakenly assigned undefined to `si` and arguments of *some other function* to `q` (it's an arguments object, not a plain array)

Comment: It looks as if someone used `let si, q = arguments;` instead of `let [si, q] = arguments;` in the other function (missing square brackets, but still valid js), though I'm not sure how it could pass through the type checker. Maybe it could pass an older type checker, only becoming a compile error in a newer version? What is the compilation error message in 5.3.3?

Comment: It turns out the function was working, and there's some other problem.  I didn't fully understand that sourcemap could make a real mess of variable values in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the function was working, and there's some other problem. I didn't fully understand that sourcemap could make a real mess of variable values in the console.  Toggling sourcemap off gives the correct value in the console.